# Close Form if SQL Query is empty

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a form to conclude ongoing operations with an sql query that will only show me the ongoing ops on the combobox. If there are no ongoing ops the program crashes! How do i prevent it from crashing?

```
Public conexao As New MySqlConnection
Public comando As New MySqlCommand
Public result As MySqlDataReader
Public r3 As MySqlDataReader
Public bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
Public strsql As String

Private Sub editarops_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    conexao.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user =root; database = frota;"
    conexao.Open()
    comando.Connection = conexao
    strsql = "SELECT codtrab, carga, origem, destino, estado, dataini FROM trabalhos "
    comando.Connection = conexao
    strsql = "SELECT codtrab, carga, origem, destino, estado, dataini FROM trabalhos "
        r3 = comando.ExecuteReader
        bs.DataSource = r3
        ComboBox1.Text = bs.Current(0)
        tboxfunc.Text = bs.Current(1)
        TextBox1.Text = bs.Current(2)
        TextBox2.Text = bs.Current(3)
        TextBox3.Text = bs.Current(5)
        Atualizar.Enabled = True
        Cancelar.Enabled = True
        r3.Close()

        Dim sStmt1 As String = "Select codtrab from trabalhos where estado = 'En Route' "
        Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand(sStmt1, conexao)
        Dim da1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable("trabalhos")
        da1.Fill(dt1)

        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt1
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "codtrab"
        da1.Dispose()
        repor()
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Enabled = False
        TextBox3.Enabled = False
        TextBox4.Enabled = False
        TextBox5.Enabled = False
        TextBox6.Enabled = False
        tboxfunc.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: May be you Need to check bs.HasRows before reading the records?

Comment: No. I don't know how to create exceptions for this particular situation. I was looking to create an IF to make me go back to another form if the query was empty.

Comment: bs doenst recognize hasrows syntax so i tried if r3.hasrows = true then execute the code else close and show another form. however it keeps crashing on this line  r3 = comando.ExecuteReader